# iOS Swipe Gesture - Time delay for swipe

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have an `UIWebview` where i'm loading multiple URL's using SwipeGesture i'm swiping to next page. I have used this code to do this,

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer* swipeUpGestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeUpFrom:)];
swipeUpGestureRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
```

in `handleSwipeUpFrom` method i'm loading next URL in my `webview`. 
Everything works **PERFECTLY**. But the swipe is works so fastly. I want to make some delay to it, any ideas....

Answer (score 1):

It may be a bit messier, but if no one has a cleaner solution, try this:

```
- (void)handleSwipeUpFrom:(id)sender
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(anotherMethod:) withObject:object afterDelay:1.0];
}
```

Comment: I agree. If you want a delay, insert a delay. The standard way to do that is with delayed performance: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch11.html#_delayed_performance

Comment: object is if you need to pass any information onto the secondary method (possibly the direction). If needed, your secondary method would look like: `- (void)anotherMethod:(id)object` 
if you don't need to pass anything, you can `withObject: nil`